# How to add background image using AWS SES Email Template

Tags: css, amazon-web-services, background-image, amazon-ses, base64url

From EC2 Linux, using AWS SES email template I am trying to send an email with background image. However, image and the script build in json located in the same path. But still I am not able to see background image in an email.

Below is the HTML in json which I am using.

"HtmlPart": "body{background-image: url(\"home/ec2-user/Test/Sample-Backgrd.jpg\");background-color: #cccccc;\r\n}</style>"

Can anybody help me if there is any issue in above script?

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the public path(https://... to the image or encode the image(for instance to base64 and provide it in the html)

Comment: for https, do I need to install httpd service in Linux?

Comment: It would be much easier to convert this image to the base64 and send it using it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried your recommendation but still not getting background image in an email.

Comment: {
  "Template": {
    "TemplateName": "myTemplate22",
    "SubjectPart": "Latest JOB Details",
"HtmlPart": "<html><style>body{background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL/2wBDAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjL/wgARCAUcAuADASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAGwAAAwE

It's a long string. Let me know if there is any issue in it.

Comment: @gihansalith - can you please help me here?